# Armature display can't be set in solid or textured mode : is this a bug of blender 2.8?

Tags: armature, bones, wireframe, object-mode

I'm trying to display the armature in solid or textured mode by activating the option that's under the **Object/Viewport display/display as**,but it does not work. Infact the armature is visibile only in **wire mode** even if **solid or textured** is selected. Is thig a bug ? let me know.

[image: u]

Comment: maybe you should share your file so that we can test

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T64332

Comment: If I go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Viewport Display and deactivate Shapes (which actually deactivates the customs), it will display the bones as expected, so I may have something to see with your version/system? So yes probably a bug

Comment: which blender version did u use ? it should be the same. Anyway,I've just upgraded blender.

Comment: I opened it with the last 2.8 version

Comment: you should use :  2.80 (sub 59), branch: master, commit date: 2019-04-26 06:00, hash: rB513b71c89ad0

Comment: I think Toggle Xray will do that to your armatures.